# Eyebrow Trimming During Sefira

Tags: halacha, sefirat-ha-omer, hair, face

Are there any known halacha- or responsa- sources that deal with the permitting or prohibiting of trimming eyebrows during Sefira? I'm wondering if eyebrows fall into the "regular" category of haircut prohibition during Sefira or if perhaps eyebrow trimming is somehow halachically different from a regular haircut and therefore permitted.

Comment: Is this for a man or woman?

Comment: I am interested in the answer as it may apply to both instances.

Answer (score 5):

Piskei Teshuvos 493:7 cites the Sefer "Bein Pesach Le'Shavuos" (9:11) in the name of R' Shlomo Zalman Auerbach and R' Shmuel Vozner that plucking eyebrows or eyelashes during Sefiras Haomer is permitted although it is done for beatification, since this is not characterized as "תספורת" (cutting).

Rabbi Gavriel Zinner also brings this ruling in Nitei Gavriel ([Pesach vol. 3 49:4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46449&st=&pgnum=280), see [Hilchos Bein Hametzarim 19:4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46439&st=&pgnum=130)) in the above Rabbis' names, but notes that R' Moshe Feinstein did not permit mourners to shave their eyebrows during first 30 days of mourning.

Comment: תספורת is cutting, but used related to hair specifically.

Comment: @DoubleAA Well actually the next sentence in Piskey Teshuvos is that any other hair in the body *is* considered תספורת, based on Shulchan Aruch 551:12 (regarding the days before Tisha Be'av): תספורת שבוע זה, אחד ראשו ואחד כל שער שבו אסור.

Comment: So why is eyebrow hair not included in כל שער שבו?

Comment: @DoubleAA Not sure, maybe it's "plucking" vs. cutting.